# Unicode shortcut not working on external keyboard

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

To add unicode symbols, on my laptop I can simply type `(left) Ctrl+Shift+u` and then add the specific number for the unicode symbol.

However, when I try to do the same with an attached external keyboard, nothing happens. This works if I use the right Ctrl key, but that makes me require 2 hands.

Anybody know how I can enable this for my external keyboard?
I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: after the external keyboard is attached, what keyboard layout is being used in Settings > Languages and Region Input Sources and does it match you external device?

Comment: It says English (US) and it does match. My keyboard has the same problem with my laptop so maybe you could help with how to configure the keyboard.

Comment: mine is set English (UK)